# Can I automate a simple commit push AND merge request to multiple repositories in order to trigger a webhook that triggers an external pipeline?

Tags: github, automation, webhooks, payload

I work in manual QA testing. As part of regression testing, I test within the following SCM repositories:

- Azure
- Bitbucket Org/Server
- Github
- GitLab

In each of these, I test by doing 2 things: 1) Make a simple commit to a branch 2) Make a Pull Request. These 2 actions prompt a webhook trigger, which start an external pipeline.
I was asked to automate this process. Is there a way to automate a simple commit on a branch and a PR?

I have looked for solutions but google might not understand my question as I'm not getting relevant information. I may be able to get by without doing an actual commmit/PR and clicking 'Redeliver' in 'Recent Deliveries', but I'm not sure how to automate this as I've never worked in automation.